# Is there any Javascript function which does regex match from specified index

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there function which work as:

```
var regex=/\s*(\w+)/;
var s="abc def ";
var m1=regex.exec(s,0); // -> matches "abc"
var m2=regex.exec(s,3); // -> matches "def"
```

I know the alternative is:

```
var regex=/\s*(\w+)/;
var s="abc def ";
var m1=regex.exec(s); // -> matches "abc"
var m2=regex.exec(s.substring(3)); // -> matches " def"
```

But I worry about that if s is very long and s.substring is called many times, some implementation may work in bad efficiency in which copy long strings many times.

Comment: You could put `.{3}` at the beginning of the regex.

Comment: I assume you know that in this case you can just fire `\w+` and then walk each individual match?  I'm guessing this is a reduction of your actual scenario, though...

Comment: How about profiling your code?  Or looking at the implementation of a JavaScript virtual machine?  Strings in JavaScript are immutable, so a good implementation would share the space for the characters and not copy them.  So yeah, `substring` makes a new object, but does not _necessarily_ copy the character data.  The length of your string may well be irrelevant. At any rate, to ensure you don't have an X-Y problem here, consider using the `g` flag, since you are probably trying to find words over and over again, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can make `exec` start at a particular index if the regex has the `g` global modifier.

```
var regex=/\s*(\w+)/g; // give it the "g" modifier

regex.lastIndex = 3;   // set the .lastIndex property to the starting index

var s="abc def ";

var m2=regex.exec(s); // -> matches "def"
```

If your first code example had the `g` modifier, then it would work as you wrote it, for the very same reason above. With `g`, it automatically sets the `.lastIndex` to the index past the end of the last match, so the next call would start there.

So it depends on what you need.

If you don't know how many matches there will be, the common approach would be to run `exec` in a loop.

```
var match,
    regex = /\s*(\w+)/g,
    s = "abc def ";

while(match = regex.exec(s)) {
    alert(match);
}
```

Or as a `do-while`.

```
var match,
    regex = /\s*(\w+)/g,
    s = "abc def ";

do {
    match = regex.exec(s);
    if (match)
        alert(match);
} while(match);
```

Comment: +1 a nice useful answer, reminding people of `g`, which is probably the way the OP _wants_ to do things. :)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I want to do!

Comment: @hoge1e3: You're welcome. And I changed my wording just a little because I think I misunderstood at first. You don't need to manually set the `.lastIndex` if you ultimately want all the matches in the string. You'd just do like your first example, but include `g`. Or you can run `exec` in a loop. I'll update with a loop example.

Comment: @hoge1e3 If you have a string with words separated by white space, and you want to get an array of all the words without white space, you could use `a_string_with_words_separated_with_space.split(/\s+/);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any regular expression method that can do this. If you are worried about performance, I would just store the full string and the snipped string so `substring` is only ever called once:

```
var regex=/\s*(\w+)/;
var s="abc def ";
var shorts = s.substring(3);
var m1=regex.exec(s); // -> matches "abc"
var m2=regex.exec(shorts); // -> matches " def"
```